# How to get column and row index(y and x) of a given item in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

for example, I have a 3x3 numpy array as below

```
a=numpy.array([3,2,1],
              [2,5,6],
              [4,7,8])
```

if the given value is 8,then I should get something like [3,3]
if the given value is 2, then I should get [0,1] and [1,0] since there are two '2's in the array.

**I know this is straightforward with looping,** but I was wondering if there's an efficient "Pythonic" way (or with any fancy numpy function)to solve it,with minimum lines of code. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.argwhere`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html#numpy.argwhere):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[3, 2, 1],
              [2, 5, 6],
              [4, 7, 8]])

print np.argwhere(a == 8)

>>> [[2 2]]

print np.argwhere(a == 2)

>>> [[0 1]
     [1 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you index of the array in tuple.

```
np.where(a == 3) # (array([0]), array([0]))
np.where(a == 2) # (array([0, 1]), array([1, 0]))
```